# Python sorting methods

Tags: python, sorting

Does python use the same sorting method in all cases? For example, a few cases:

```
s = "some text here"
l = ["some", "items", "here"]

sorted(s)
sorted(l)
sorted(s, key=lambda x: ord('l')-ord(x))
l.sort()
```

Is it always the same? If so, which algorithm(s) is used for the above?

Comment: What is the point of this question? It isn't very clear. Which of the above outputs do you consider problematic or indicative of Python using multiple sorting algorithms under the hood?

Comment: @JohnColeman I'm just curious actually, no problem.

Comment: Curiosity is good, but in that case @Grismar is probably correct that it is a duplicate

Comment: @Daved542 can you please indicate if the question linked as a duplicate does in fact answer your question? Otherwise, please amend your question to be more specific, so we can help provide an answer - curiosity is fine as a reason, the question is valid, but I think it has already been answered on SO.

Comment: @Grismar sure that seems like a good link, though a lot of the details are buried in the "link to cython". Thanks for the link.

Comment: It also has a comment by Tim Peters, the actual author of timsort, which is the one-word answer to your question. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort